# Slow Excel automation?

Tags: powershell, excel, automation, office-interop, vba

I'm using the following Powershell script to remove the `NumberFormat` of the cells in a column for a lot of files so all the fractions will be displayed. The column may have decimal, text or date, etc; only these decimal/currency formatted (with format of `0*` or `*#*`) cells need to be applied

However it's slow (check/update two or three cells every second). Is there a better/faster way to do it?

```
    $WorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($fileName)
    $WorkSheet = $WorkBook.Worksheets.Item(1)
    $cell = $WorkSheet.Cells

    $ColumnIndex = 10 # The column may have decimal, text or date, etc.
    $i = 2

    while ($cell.Item($i, 1).value2 -ne $Null)
      # Replace it to find the last row# of column 1 may cut the time in half? How?
    {
        $c = $cell.Item($i, $ColumnIndex)

        if (($c.NumberFormat -like "0*") -or $c.NumberFormat -like "*#*")
        {
            "$i : $($c.NumberFormat) $($c.value2) "
            $c.NumberFormat = $Null
        }
        $i++
    }
```

**Update:**

Will the .Net `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` much faster?
Or convert the files to xlsx format and use `System.IO.Package.IO`?

Comment: Can you quantify how slow it runs? is there an example file you can upload for us to test against?

Comment: It takes a half hour to process 12 Excel files. The size of the Excel files are usually 60KB and there are several hundred to a couple of thousands rows in each file.

Comment: From my own point of view I would need a sample file along with metrics as to how long it takes you to process said file with your script in order to really assist more, or to see if I could improve upon the execution speed any. You can wrap your code within Measure-Command to see how long something takes to run.

Comment: Since your calls are already using Interop (although you may not realise it) you're unlikely to see a performance improvement from early binding to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`.

Comment: You may be able to do some filtering so you don't have to loop each cell (which is very very slow to do).  If (and only if) you can guarantee the values in the number fields are never going to clash with the dates (which are stored as numbers, like 41284 is 1/1/2000) then you could exclude anything above that and that would also remove the text cells.  I'll work up a sample if I get a chance

Comment: @JamesSnell Thanks. I found looping the cells very slow and filtering may help. Is it possible to filter by `NumberFormat`? What if most of the cells have `NumberFormat` of `0` or `0.00`?

Comment: equvilant vba code would be much faster than that

Comment: You can use SpecialCells Method to get your range which has constants and then loop through those? See this link on SpecialCells http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb178148%28v=office.12%29.aspx For example this would give you a range of cells which have constants (numbers, currency, dates) `Columns(10).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)` Let me know if you want a VBA/VB.Net/C# code which you can convert to Powershell

Comment: Here is one post in powershell which shows how to use SpecialCells Method. See the answer posted by `
zx38` http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/winserverpowershell/thread/28c56c38-6828-4053-a600-bd460df44ecf

Comment: Have you turned off the screen update, it might be even slower when changing cell format. Set:
    $Excel.ScreenUpdating = False

Comment: @SiddharthRout I got the error of 'Exception calling "SpecialCells" with "2" argument(s): "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A01A8' when call `$cell.SpecialCells(11, 2)` or `$cell.SpecialCells(11)`.

Comment: @79E09796 Turning off the screen update may help some. I commented out the update statement and it's also very slow.

Comment: Try `$cell.SpecialCells(2, 1)` Which is equivalent to `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)`... The value of `xlCellTypeConstants` is `2` and `xlNumbers` is `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I improved the speed after read the comment. Thanks all.

1. Try to reduce the access of the cells as much as possible. I deleted the output line `"$i : $($c.NumberFormat) $($c.value2) "` and change

   `if (($c.NumberFormat -like "0*") -or $c.NumberFormat -like "*#*")`
   to
   `$f = $c.NumberFormat`
   `if ($f -like "0*" -or $f -like "*#*")`
2. I also use `$lastRow = $cell.SpecialCells(11, 1).Row` to get the last row number and change the loop to `while ($i -le $lastRow)`.
3. `$Excel.ScreenUpdating = False` also helped reduced some time.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!!!! Adding ScreenUpdating = false reduced the time of my border drawing from 70 seconds to 3 seconds!